# Inequality in $L^p$ involving integral

Tags: functional-analysis

This is from Folland chapter 6. exercise 30.

Suppose that K is a nonnegative measurable function on $(0,\infty)$ such that 
$\int_0^{\infty}K(x)x^{s-1}=\theta(s)<\infty$ for $0<s<1$.

1. If $1 < p <\infty,\ p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$, and $f, g$ are nonnegative
   measurable functions  on $(0,\infty)$, then (with $\int =
       \int_0^{\infty}$)

   $$\int\int K(xy)f(x)g(y) dxdy \leq \theta(p^{-1})\left[ \int x^{p -
       2} f(x)^p dx\right]^{\frac{1}{p}} \left[\int g(x)^q
       dx\right]^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
2. The operator $Tf(x) = \int_0^{\infty} K(xy)f(y) dy$ is bounded
   on $L^2((0, \infty))$ with norm $\leq\theta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

---

For item 1. I've found the answer :-)

---

For item 2. I'm not sure which norm to use for $Tf$. Based on previous item it would be natural to take $||\cdot||_1$ but then the second item $||g||_q$ fails to be finite. And if it is $||\cdot||_2$ I have no idea what to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that bounded on $L^2$ means bounded as an operator from $L^2$ to $L^2$, so that you have to take $p=q=2$. The inequality you have proved is then
$$
\Bigl|\int Tf(y)\,g(y)\,dy\Bigr|\le\theta(1/2)\|f\|_2\|g\|_2\quad\forall f,g\in L^2.
$$

Comment: If $Tf$ is bounded from $L^2$ to $L^2$ shoudn't then be $||Tf||_2=\left(\int\left(\int K(xy)f(y)dy\right)^2 dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \theta(\frac{1}{2}) $ the inequality I have to prove?

Comment: You need to prove $\|Tf\|_2\le\theta(1/2)\|f\|_2$. This follows from the inequality in my answer.

Comment: That's right, The left side of Your inequality is just different form of writing the left side of inequality in a. Then square of $||Tf||_2$ is left side of your inequality with $g(y)=Tf(y)$.